# Internet Connection Sharing program hangs Windows 11 mechanism

Tags: c++, windows

I wrote a simple program that share Internet connection in Windows. This mechanism in Windows is very convenient, but has one drawback - after each loading of the OS one should manually disable and enable ICS. My program works one time perfectly, but hangs the mechanism of ICS next bootstrap, and I must login into a server and do a trick - share another connection and after it share the Internet connection again (without the trick the OS says that another connection with weird name is already shared). I am not sure how to debug that program, please, look into the code, any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <exception>
#include <windows.h>
#include <netlistmgr.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <netcon.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <winerror.h>
namespace po = boost::program_options;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
CComPtr<INetworkListManager> pNLM;
HRESULT hr;
void err_to_mes(HRESULT r){
  _com_error err(r);
  std::cout << err.ErrorMessage() << "\n";
  std::cout << "HRESULT facility = " << HRESULT_FACILITY(r)
    << " HRESULT severity = " << HRESULT_SEVERITY(r)
    << " HRESULT code = " << HRESULT_CODE(r) << " ";
  switch(r){
    case E_ABORT:
      std::cout << "The operation was aborted\n";
      break;
    case E_FAIL:
      std::cout << "An unspecified error occurred\n";
      break;
    case E_INVALIDARG:
      std::cout << "One of the parameters is invalid\n";
      break;
    case E_NOINTERFACE:
      std::cout << "A specified interface is not supported\n";
      break;
    case E_NOTIMPL:
      std::cout << "A specified method is not implemented\n";
      break;
    case E_OUTOFMEMORY:
      std::cout << "The method was unable to allocate required memory\n";
      break;
    case E_POINTER:
      std::cout << "A pointer passed as a parameter is not valid\n";
      break;
    case E_UNEXPECTED:
      std::cout << "The method failed for unknown reasons\n";
      break;
    default:
      std::cout << "Something criptic happened\n";
  }
}
bool cm_crt(){
  CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NetworkListManager, NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(INetworkListManager), (LPVOID*)&pNLM);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) { return true; }
  else { return false; }
}
bool enable_sharing(std::wstring& con_name){
  // enum connections until we get one that we
  // can convert into an INetSharingConfiguration
  CoInitializeSecurity (NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT,
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
  INetSharingManager * pNSM = NULL;
  hr = ::CoCreateInstance (__uuidof(NetSharingManager), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
    __uuidof(INetSharingManager), (void**)&pNSM);
  if (!pNSM){ std::cout << "failed to create NetSharingManager object\n"; }
  else {
    INetConnection * pNC = NULL;
    INetSharingEveryConnectionCollection * pNSECC = NULL;
    hr = pNSM->get_EnumEveryConnection (&pNSECC);
    if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      err_to_mes(hr);
      return false;
    }
    // if(hr == 0x80070005){ std::cout << "access is denied\n"; }
    if (!pNSECC) { std::cout << "failed to get EveryConnectionCollection!\n"; }
    else { // enumerate connections
      IEnumVARIANT * pEV = NULL;
      IUnknown * pUnk = NULL;
      hr = pNSECC->get__NewEnum (&pUnk);
      if(pUnk){
        hr = pUnk->QueryInterface (__uuidof(IEnumVARIANT), (void**)&pEV);
        pUnk->Release();
      }
      if (pEV) {
        VARIANT v;
        VariantInit (&v);
        BOOL bFoundIt = FALSE;
        while (S_OK == pEV->Next (1, &v, NULL)) {
          if (V_VT (&v) == VT_UNKNOWN) {
            V_UNKNOWN (&v)->QueryInterface (__uuidof(INetConnection),
              (void**)&pNC);
            if (pNC){
              NETCON_PROPERTIES *pNP;
              pNC->GetProperties(&pNP);
              if (con_name == pNP->pszwName){ // got the connection
                bFoundIt = TRUE;
              }
              if (bFoundIt == FALSE) {
                pNC->Release();
                pNC = NULL;
              }
            }
          }
          VariantClear(&v);
          if(bFoundIt == TRUE){ break; }
        }
        pEV->Release();
      }
      pNSECC->Release();
    }
    if (pNC == NULL) {
        std::cout << "failed to find a valid connection!\n";
        return false;
    }
    INetSharingConfiguration * pNSC = NULL;
    hr = pNSM->get_INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection (pNC, &pNSC);
    pNC->Release(); // don't need this anymore
    if (!pNSC) {
        std::cout << "can't make INetSharingConfiguration object!\n";
        return false;
    } else {
      hr = pNSC->DisableSharing();
      if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to disable sharing\n";
        err_to_mes(hr);
        return false;
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(10000ms);
      hr = pNSC->EnableSharing(ICSSHARINGTYPE_PUBLIC);
      if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) { // -2147220991
        std::cout << "unable to share, operation result is: " << hr << "\n";
        err_to_mes(hr);
        return false; }
    }
  }
  pNSM->Release();
  return true;
}
int wmain(int ac, wchar_t* av[]){
  boost::optional<std::wstring> connection;
  if(!cm_crt()) {
    std::cerr << "Error com creation network list manager\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  VARIANT_BOOL bIsConnectedInternet;
  for(hr = E_FAIL; !SUCCEEDED(hr); hr
    = pNLM->get_IsConnectedToInternet(&bIsConnectedInternet)){
    if(!bIsConnectedInternet){ std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms); }
  }
  try {
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()("help", "prepend -- to option")
      ("connection", po::wvalue(&connection), "any string without spaces");
    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::wcommand_line_parser(ac, av).options(desc).run(), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
    if(vm.count("help")){
      std::cout << desc << "\n";
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if(connection){
      std::wcout << "Connection name was set to "
        << *connection << "\n";
      if(!enable_sharing(*connection)){
        std::cout << "unable sharing\n";
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "Connection name was not set, continue without sharing.\n";
    }
  }
  catch(std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  catch(...) {
    std::cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  pNLM.Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile string:
`cl /MD /EHsc /Fe:share_con.exe share_con.cpp /I C:\boost /link /LIBPATH:C:\boost\stage\lib`

Comment: valgrind........??

Comment: How did you manage to write that whole code without knowing how to debug it?

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I have restricted access to the target machine unfortunately.